# Plugin or brush for transforming a photo to a fractal in gimp?

Tags: gimp, brush

Folks,

I've been looking all over for a plugin or brush that will help me take a photo and reduce it to that 'electric look' (or fractal?) that i'm seeing in various places. I'd vastly prefer one for Gimp.  Does anyone know how these are being done? I'm seening references to fractalius for photoshop, but what about gimp?

Examples:

[image]

[image]

Comment: This iterative edge-finding filter is, technically, not "fractal."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A GIMP plugin which comes close to this effect is the "Rodilius effect" from the [GREYC's Magic for Image Computing (G'MIC) plugin](http://registry.gimp.org/node/13469) collection.

[image]
<sup>Image source: [GIMP plugin registry](http://registry.gimp.org/node/13469)</sup>

Comment: I'd swear i replied to this months ago, but thank you Takkat. This was just what i was looking for!

Answer (score 4):

It's just Fractalis:

http://www.redfieldplugins.com/filterFractalius.htm

No idea if GIMP is supported.

Answer (score 1):

Gimp is supported with Fractalius.  G'MIC's Rodilius is one of the best freeware options, but now you can create closer effects to this using Google's Deep dream settings from sites such as Dreamscope.com or Ostagram.