# How can I apply an oil painting effect to a photo?

Tags: photoshop-effects, effects, photo-editing

I really want to do this kind of effect where it looks like a person is disintegrating away, but I have no idea what it is called:

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Plugin or brush for transforming a photo to a fractal in gimp?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/18235/plugin-or-brush-for-transforming-a-photo-to-a-fractal-in-gimp)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

THanks To Bala's clue in the comment.... I found the original source photo....

It's merely Adobe Photoshop's **Oil Paint Filter**

Here's one with these settings:

[image]

[image]

This is a completely new image generated by running the oil paint filter on the same source photo. This is not merely a reposting of your sample image.

Comment: I'm glad to help with a single word and yes I'm the fan of thala ajith.

Answer (score 0):

The Oil Paint filter mentioned in Scott's answer was removed from Photoshop in version CC-2014. For those using Windows, [Adobe has recommended](http://blogs.adobe.com/photoshopdotcom/2014/04/photoshop-spring-cleaning.html) using the GREYCstoration plugin:

> Oil Paint is a very cool filter, but relied on a very large and
>   complex code library used for an outdated technology (Pixel Bender)
>   that is no longer supported.
>
> ***Workarounds for Oil Paint:***
>
> *Update/note: Here’s a windows only plug-in which may be useful
>   discussed here: http://www.modelmayhem.com/po.php?thread_id=926714*

**Update**: It's back as of CC-2019 (*thanks @Tetsujin*)

Comment: I haven't been following its progress over the years, but it's there in CC2019